# jQuery - for inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have tried to create a for loop in jQuery. it has worked!

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $('.infosegment2-1-'+i).click(function() {
            $(".p_expandable").not('.p_expandable2-1-'+i).slideUp();
            $('.p_expandable2-1-'+i).slideToggle('default');
        });
    })(i);
}
```

When I clicked on infosegment2-1-i it has showed expandable content of it and so on...
The thing is that I need to do same with infosegment2_2_i etc...

I wanted to put for inside for... the syntax seems to be OK but it does not work at all...

```js
for (var $b = 1; $b <= 10; $b++) {
    for (var $i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {  
        $('.infosegment2-'+$b+'-'+$i).click(function() {
            $(".p_expandable").not('.p_expandable2-'+$b+'-'+$i).slideUp();
            $('.p_expandable2-'+$b+'-'+$i).slideToggle('default');
        });
    }
}
```

I have used https://jshint.com/ to check what is wrong with my code, this was the output of that site:

> Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. ($, $b, $i)

I do not know why it counts $ at start of line as variable as well...
So I think I have to edit syntax around variables somehow, but I do not know what to do

EDIT: Here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<div id="content_submenu2">
    <div class=" submenu2_div1 sd">
        <div class="grid gird-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">

            <div class=" mx-auto bg-black bg-opacity-10 rounded-b-2xl ">                    
                    <img class="infosegment2-1-1 images" src="images/chess-set">  
                    
                    <h3>Chess Set</h3>
                    
                    <div class="p_expandable2-1-1 p_expandable">
                        <p>
                           You have expanded this section by clicking on image.
                        </p>
                    </div>      
            </div>
        <div class="mx-auto bg-black bg-opacity-10 rounded-b-2xl">

        <img class="infosegment2-1-2 images" src="images/checkers">
        <h3>Checkers</h3>
       
        <div class="p_expandable2-1-2 p_expandable">
        <p>
            This is checkers' expandable text
        </p>
        </div>
    
    </div>                        
</div>
```

I have a grid of photos with h3, and each img is infosegment which after click expands p_expandable div and hides other p_expandable divs .... BTW I am using tailwind and jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: To avoid having to use the multiple loops and closures you can instead use common classes in your HTML and traverse the DOM to relate the elements together. This makes the code much simpler, more extensible and easier to maintain. If you could show an example of how your HTML is structured, we can give you an example of how to do this.

Comment: could share a sandebox or your html code , as Rory mentioned  you should avoid loops ( multiple closure created ) in term of performance !

Comment: Added a html sample...

Comment: `$` is a variable referring to jQuery. It is a global variable. You can tell jshint about it using `/* globals $ */` at the top. Not an answer, just a hint about jshint ;-).

Comment: Do you know when jQuery selects something it implicitly loops when you chain a call from it? You often don't need to use any explicit "for" loop at all. `$('[class^=infosegment2]').click(function() {...})` will select every element with a class that _starts with_ (`^=`) "infosegment2" and attach a click handler to all of them.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're after is to expand the paragraph adjacent to each image, and simultaneously contract all open containers, this should do:

```js
$('.images').click(function() {
  const slideEl = $(this).siblings('.p_expandable');

  $('.p_expandable').not(slideEl).slideUp();
  slideEl.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.p_expandable {overflow: hidden; display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content_submenu2">
  <div class=" submenu2_div1 sd">
    <div class="grid gird-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">

      <div class=" mx-auto bg-black bg-opacity-10 rounded-b-2xl ">
        <img class="infosegment2-1-1 images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

        <h3>Chess Set</h3>

        <div class="p_expandable2-1-1 p_expandable">
          <p>
            You have expanded this section by clicking on image.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mx-auto bg-black bg-opacity-10 rounded-b-2xl">
        <img class="infosegment2-1-2 images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <h3>Checkers</h3>

        <div class="p_expandable2-1-2 p_expandable">
          <p>
            This is checkers' expandable text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Examples of jQuery accordions are as plentiful as sand on a beach. I suggest you look at a few for ideas.